# Latest stable version of wildfly

Tags: server, wildfly

Which is the latest stable version of wildfly?because we are going to migrate our application from jboss AS 7 to the latest stable version of WildFly

Answer (score 0):

It's 13.0.0.Final,
You can find it on the offcial website of wildfly 
http://wildfly.org/downloads/

Comment: Just as a note too WildFly is now doing quarterly releases http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/wildfly-dev/2017-December/006250.html. The next release, WildFly 14, should be this week.